# Get triangle to show outside of a div, floating over the div next to it

Tags: html, css

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T61nh.png)

I know how to make the triangle, my issue is that is is being created INSIDE of the box. If I set "left" to 100%, the box will disappear behind the right side of the box instead of going outside of the box over the next one.

Here is the Pen I am working on to try and get this to work: 
[My Code](https://codepen.io/rperry1886/pen/zyGRwP)

HTML:

```
<div class="square title">
<div class="content">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-cell ">
            <ul>This demo shows you can center multiple types of content :
                <li>Text</li>
                <li>Images</li>
                <li>Lists</li>
                <li>... (you can also do it with forms)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="square">
 <div class="content">
     <div class="table">
         <div class="table-cell ">
           <p>Hello World!</p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: center;
    }

    .square {
     float:left;
     position: relative;
     width: 33%;
     padding-bottom : 33%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    /*     margin:1.66%; */
     background-color:#1E1E1E;
     overflow:hidden;
    /*     border: solid 1px red; */
    margin: 5px;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    height:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 5%;

}
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/*  For list */
ul{
    text-align:left;
    margin:5% 0 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
li{
    margin: 0 0 0 5%;
    padding:0;
}

.title::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid green;
  left: 95%;
/*   top: 45%; */
/*   z-index: 999; */
}
```

I tried making a whole new div around the square and setting that to have the triangle, but it made the triangle go all the way to the right of the screen, even without setting anything for the left or right.

I also tried z-index but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: remove overflow:hidden and then add z-index

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with only background:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: grey;
}

.box:last-child {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,grey 49.8%,transparent 50%) 0 calc(50% - 15px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,grey 49.8%,transparent 50%) 0 calc(50% + 15px),
    #000;
  background-size:30px 30px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve the issue with the first thing you suggested, getting rid of the overflow and adding the z-index. 

I don't know if the background solution will work for me or not. Ultimately, the boxes are meant to be a responsive grid of boxes showing products, and the arrow will point to the details. 

I am going to try using the background though and see where I can get with that.

Thanks again!